# How to show RequiredField validators before client-side JavaScript?

Tags: asp.net

i want to show the Require filed validators first.then i want to validate the page controls.
how to acheive this.

i wrote onclientclick event like this.
 
but i want to show required filed validators first .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the below

```
if(Page_ClientValidate("Validation Group"))
{
}
```